# How to manage roles and permission in Django Rest framework mongoengine

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-mongodb-engine

I am building a Restapi using Django and Rest framework and mongoengine, so far all requests require a user to be authenticated and check against a token.

But now I need to allow different actions to different users. I don't know where to begin. Any guidelines ?

For example I want only the admin to be able to write and read users objects:

```
class UsersViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UsersSerializer

    def me(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the chapter on [custom permisssion](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions). You will want to extend `permissions.BasePermission` and provide the authentication logic inside `has_permission`.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class CustomUserPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # return True if user has permission
        pass
```

Then inside your view.

```
class UsersViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (CustomUserPermission,)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you